# Why am I getting a "cannot find symbol" error in my java program when I compile?

Tags: java, return

I am trying to return the value of my boolean variable localFound at the end of my code but when I compile, I get an error that says it cannot find the symbol.  I know this is an error that deals with the scope of the variable, but I do not know how to fix it.  How do I get my program to return the correct value?  Thanks.

```
public static boolean addIfNotEmpty(DvdTreeNode root, String movieToCommand) {

  if (root == null) {
    return false;
  }
  addIfNotEmpty(root.getRight(), movieToCommand);
  if (root.getItem().getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(movieToCommand)) {
    root.getItem().addCopy();
    System.out.println("You have added another copy of \""
    + movieToCommand
    + "\" to the inventory.");
    boolean localFound;
    localFound = true;
  }
  addIfNotEmpty(root.getLeft(), movieToCommand);
  return localFound;
} // end addIfNotEmpty
```

Comment: Please mark the line the error specifies so it is easier to find.

Comment: put `boolean localFound;` outside `if` statement. you can put just below the method declaration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`localFound` is not defined in the scope of your `return` statement.  It only exists within your `if` statement.

Move the declaration outside of your `if` statement, and initialize it to some default value, such as `false`.

Comment: I did that and now it tells me that the variable might not have been initialized.

Comment: @jdc987 then set it to false initially, because you are setting it to true (the opposite) in the if - boolean localFound = false;

Comment: Do as @Bucco and Makoto say, or add an `else` statement setting it to some value. The error you are getting is because the compiler sees that there are cases (when `!root.getItem().getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(movieToCommand`, in your case) where the variable will not be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

The *localFound* variable is declared within the *if* statement, thus, it's not visible outside that statement. Try declaring it right before the *if* statement (outside it) and you'll get the code compiling.